# Trying to Target <span> Content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, rotation, target, html

I am using the jqueryrotate plugin and it works if I want to rotate the content of the parent id, but I want to rotate a span that is a child of the id. I am not finding the right syntax to target the span.

```
$(".faqq").click(function(){
        var showthis = "#" + this.id + "a";

            /* .plus is the class name of the span I am trying to target */
        var rotatethis = "#" + this.id + " .plus";

        $(showthis).slideToggle('fast');
        $(rotatethis).rotate({
            angle: 0, 
            animateTo:225
          })
    });
```

Can someone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT: HTML Example:

```
<p id="faqq1" class="faqq">
            <strong>Q. Where is my order? <span class="plus">+</span></strong>
        </p>
<p id="faqq1a" class="faqa">
            A. You can ...what we know.
        </p>
```

Comment: Not without seeing your html as well, I'd imagine. And if you post a live demo (perhaps at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)) that would help.

Comment: I added the html, but it's using a jquery plugin so I don't know how to add that on JS Fiddle, but the question is more to the basics of jQuery, I'm guessing, I just can't find the answer in searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `.plus` has positioning that allows its position to be set.

```
$(rotatethis)
          .css('position','relative')
          .rotate({
            angle: 0, 
            animateTo:225
          });
```

You'd probably want to do this in CSS instead of with jQuery's `.css()`.

---

Side note, but I'd replace this...

```
var rotatethis = "#" + this.id + " .plus";
$(rotatethis)
```

with this...

```
$(this).find('.plus')
```

---

**EDIT:**

*Instead of `position: relative`, the issue was that `display: block` was needed.*

Comment: I added the position like you showed, but it's still not targeting the span. Is $(#id .class) the proper syntax?

Comment: Just saw your side note and changed it. Although I realize that's a better way to code it, it still isn't resolving my targeting problem.

Comment: @MichaelDavis: That's the proper syntax, but you can always search from the current element using `$(this).find('.class')`. The first thing you need to do is check the error console for errors. The second thing is to verify that a matched element was found. A quick test is `console.log( "plus: ", $(this).find('.plus').length );`, then open your browsers console to see the result.

Comment: OK, so the length was 1, which is correct. Really strange that the plugin is working for the div, but not the span. I appreciate you sticking this out with me so far.

Comment: @MichaelDavis: Not a problem. Unfortunately I don't know anything about that plugin. Have you tried setting the span as `position:absolute`? Are you able to get it repositioned with regular CSS? Also maybe it should be `display:block`?

Comment: Ah Ha! It was the display:block... I'll have to rework my html and css because it's a big mess, but it is rotating once I changed that. Like I said, thanks for sticking it out with me!